# Change or toggle sources on click

Tags: jquery

I plan to have a button to switch website themes. I've been searching here but no joy. Is it possible to change or toggle css links from the head tag of the document by using click function? I have no idea where to start or if it's possible or not. Let me know.

Example button:

```
<button type="button" class="floater btn btn-primary" title="Click to change theme"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button>
```

Comment: Do you want to change css(theme) on click?

Comment: @milankyada, yeah

Answer (score 2):

```
The idea is to disable the current style and load the new css file.
//Head
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" id="style1" />
//head
//body
<button type="button" id="addCss" class="floater btn btn-primary" title="Click to change theme"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button>   

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addCss").click(function() {
   $("#style1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("head").append("<link>");
  var css = $("head").children(":last");
  css.attr({
   rel:  "stylesheet",
   type: "text/css",
   href: "css-file-path"
  });   
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have theme .css files ready in a folder, you can try to store theme name or .css filename in localstorage/cookie and then reload the page and retrieve the .css theme.

The below code might help. I am using following code for my project based on Kendo Themes.

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu thememenu">
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.bootstrap.min">Bootstrap</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.blueopal.min">Blueopal</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.metro.min">Metro</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.black.min">Black</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.flat.min">Flat</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.material.min">Material</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.materialblack.min">Material Black</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.uniform.min">Uniform</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-css-name="kendo.silver.min">Silver</a></li>

</ul>
```

**JS**

```
    var theme = {

        changeTheme: function () {
            var selected = $(this).data("css-name");
            localStorage.setItem("theme-kendo", selected);
            window.location.reload();
        },

        loadTheme: function () {
            var theme = localStorage.getItem("theme-kendo");
            var css = $('link[href*="/Content/kendo/"]')[1];  //get my css anchor
            css.href = '/Content/kendo/' + theme + '.css';
        }
    };


    $(function () {
        theme.loadTheme();
        $('.thememenu a').on('click', theme.changeTheme);

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you

```
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

<script>
function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
    document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
}
</script>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('./css/red.css')">Red Style Sheet</button>
<button onclick="swapStyleSheet('./css/green.css')">Green Style Sheet</button>
```